# Trying to understand deferredresult performance improvement

Tags: spring, nonblocking, deferred

We are trying to follow this blog and understand deferredresult . https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/building-async-non-blocking-microservices-using-spring-patnaik/

In the blog, the person has given a normal blocking and non blocking code. I have copied it here.

The person ran jmeter to concurrently test 1000 threads for 5 minutes. He mentioned that latency and tps were different for non blocking with the code. When I try to see it using jmeter with same details, i see the same latency for both non blocking and blocking.

I have already tried decreasing and increasing the times etc.

```
    public SpringBootAppController() {
    timer = new Timer();
    ses = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
}
@RequestMapping("/blockingprocess")
public String blockingProcessing(@RequestParam(value="processingtime") long processingtime) throws InterruptedException
{
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thread.sleep(processingtime);
    //add more processing later
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeTaken = endTime-startTime;
    return  "SUCCESS. Blocking process completed in " + timeTaken + " Ms";
}
@RequestMapping("/nonblockingprocess")
public DeferredResult<String> nonBlockingProcessing(@RequestParam(value="processingtime") long processingtime) throws InterruptedException
{
    DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<String>();
    NewProcess j = new NewProcess(deferredResult, processingtime);
    ses.schedule(j,processingtime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    System.out.println("hello");
    return deferredResult;
}
```

Another class.

```
    public NewProcess(DeferredResult<String> deferredresult, long processingtime)
    {
        this.deferredresult = deferredresult;
        this.processingtime = processingtime;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String result = "SUCCESS non blocking process completed in " + processingtime + " Ms";
        deferredresult.setResult(result);
    }
```

Expected is difference and better performance for non blocking compared to blocking.

Comment: Is there a setting to do for nonblocking process in jmeter to see that the async with deferredresult is done sooner? I see the details fine on my local system print screenshots.

Comment: The article is of poor quality, IMHO. What do you intend to actually do instead of `Thread.sleep(processingtime); //add more processing later`. Because if what you intend to do is CPU-bound of has blocking IO, a solution based on a pool of 10 threads computing deferred results will be far worse than a solution based on Tomcat's much larger pool of request-handling threads. And if what you're after is only non-blocking, asynchrnous IO, then you should probably use WebFlux instead of MVC.